# AMD graphics switching support in Trusty Tahr's kernel

Tags: ati, intel-graphics, radeon, hybrid-graphics, 14.04

I upgraded to 14.04 just today and since I'm now using kernel v3.13 and according to [This link](http://kernelnewbies.org/Linux_3.13#head-f95c198f6fdc7defe36f470dc8369cf0e16898df), I should now be having automatic GPU switching

**How can I confirm that ? How can I force my graphic cards to do so ?**

My machine: **Dell Inspiron SE 7520**

My GPU (Discrete\Independent graphics card): **AMD Radeon HD 7730m**

My APU (Graphics card integrated into the processor): **Intel® Ivybridge Mobile**

Comment: Probably you need to install the driver via `addtional driver` tab, that might add some utility.

Comment: The `xorg-xserver-video-ati` driver is the current active driver. This is the driver, correct ? May be I should confirm it's version ?